# How to delete table view row from Sqlite swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

> I am trying to delete row from sqlite. I have used swipe method for
>   removal of item from sqlite, still it's not working....
>
> I have called the function deleteItem() in swipe method, and I also
>   got message "Successfully deleted row." 
>   But still row is not deleted.
>   below is my tryal code that may try to implement.

```
import UIKit
import SQLite3

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var db: OpaquePointer?
var brainList = [BrainDumpAdapter]()
var usesTallCells = false

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewHeroes: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldPowerRanking: UITextField!

@IBAction func buttonSave(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let name = textFieldName.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let powerRanking = textFieldPowerRanking.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    if(name?.isEmpty)!{
        textFieldName.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        return
    }

    if(powerRanking?.isEmpty)!{
        textFieldName.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        return
    }

    var stmt: OpaquePointer?

    let queryString = "INSERT INTO BrainDump (name, pomodoro) VALUES (?,?)"

    if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    if sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, name, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("failure binding name: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    if sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, (powerRanking! as NSString).intValue) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("failure binding name: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    if sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("failure inserting hero: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    textFieldName.text=""
    textFieldPowerRanking.text=""

    readValues()

    print("Braindump succesfully saved")
}
```

> //delete item sqlite

```
 func deleteItem(itemId: Int32)
    {
        let deleteStatementStirng = "DELETE FROM BrainDump WHERE id = ?;"
        var deleteStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, deleteStatementStirng, -1, &deleteStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK
        {     
            sqlite3_bind_int(deleteStatement, 1, itemId)

            if sqlite3_step(deleteStatement) == SQLITE_DONE
            {
                print("Successfully deleted row.")
            }
            else
            {
                print("Could not delete row.")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("DELETE statement could not be prepared")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(deleteStatement)
        print("delete")
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let c : Int32 = Int32(indexPath.row)
        deleteItem(itemId: c)   
         self.tableViewHeroes.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

> //SQLITE

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            print(brainList.count)
            return brainList.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
            let brainDump: BrainDumpAdapter
            brainDump = brainList[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = brainDump.name



            return cell
        }


        func readValues(){
            brainList.removeAll()

            let queryString = "SELECT * FROM BrainDump"

            var stmt:OpaquePointer?

            if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
                let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
                print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
                return
            }

            while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
                let id = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0)
                let name = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))
                let pomodoro = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 2)

                brainList.append(BrainDumpAdapter(id: Int(id), name: String(describing: name), pomodoro: Int(pomodoro)))
            }

            self.tableViewHeroes.reloadData()
        }




        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
                .appendingPathComponent("SQLiteDatabse.sqlite")


            if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
                print("error opening database")
            }

            if sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BrainDump (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, pomodoro INTEGER)", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
                let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
                print("error creating table: \(errmsg)")
            }

            readValues()

        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the item from the data source you used to build the tableview, as I can see you are not deleting it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {
            let c : Int32 = Int32(indexPath.row)
            deleteItem(itemId: c)   
            brainList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableViewHeroes.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for rly . But I want to delete the table row from the Sqlite database not only from list view. As per ur suggestion, we can only able to remove the table row from list view. But I want to delete that row from Sqlite database, means I want to delete that data permanently.

Comment: duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224760/how-do-i-delete-an-tableview-row-in-sqlite-swift-4/53258867#53258867

Comment: Still it's not working. Please let me know the solution, I will be thankful to you.